# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on an app that works on emulator

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

My app works well on emulator, but I got this error after I installed app on the real devices using apk.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.wiserlab.macquest, PID: 9151
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.example.wiserlab.macquest.model.CustomContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.wiserlab.macquest.model.CustomContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wiserlab.macquest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.wiserlab.macquest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4777)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.wiserlab.macquest.model.CustomContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wiserlab.macquest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.wiserlab.macquest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I am sure that class exists. Should I import that class in somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have proguard enabled maybe your code is ofuscated and the crash is about some functionality that use Reflection like Gson.

Check that the build type in the emulator is same as real devices (in debug). Also you can try setting `useProguard false` in your BuildType settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sloved by deleting the build folder and re-build.